# lineChartView axis label add extra line on the label

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swift4

hi  i want to add a line on top of every label like this

[image]

i tried

```
class XAxisRendererWithTicks: XAxisRenderer {

override func drawLabel(context: CGContext, formattedLabel: String, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any], constrainedToSize: CGSize, anchor: CGPoint, angleRadians: CGFloat) {

super.drawLabel(context: context, formattedLabel: formattedLabel, x: x, y: y, attributes: attributes, constrainedToSize: constrainedToSize, anchor: anchor, angleRadians: angleRadians)

context.beginPath()

context.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: self.viewPortHandler.contentBottom))

context.strokePath()
}}
```

and

```
let customXAxisRenderer = XAxisRendererWithTicks(viewPortHandler: lineChartView.viewPortHandler, xAxis: lineChartView.xAxis, transformer: lineChartView.getTransformer(forAxis: .left))
    lineChartView.xAxisRenderer = customXAxisRenderer
```

this can make the short line, but how to remove the short line where is no label?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by this

```
override func drawLabel(context: CGContext, formattedLabel: String, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any], constrainedToSize: CGSize, anchor: CGPoint, angleRadians: CGFloat) {

    super.drawLabel(context: context, formattedLabel: formattedLabel, x: x, y: y, attributes: attributes, constrainedToSize: constrainedToSize, anchor: anchor, angleRadians: angleRadians)

    if(formattedLabel == ""){
        return
    }
    context.beginPath()

    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: self.viewPortHandler.contentBottom))

    context.strokePath()
}
```